# PIC Microcontroller with GSM module

Tags: microcontroller, sim900, mikroc

How do I get a caller identity from sim900 using pic16f877A microcontroller meanwhile, I can make call, send SMS and answer calls but I want to be able to compare an incoming call identity with a predefined on in my program. My compiler if Mikroc. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to give `AT+CLIP=1\r` command to enable additional caller information.

Once you issue this command, any incoming call will be notified in the following format,

```
RING

+CLIP:+911234567890
```

Now just extract the number after `+CLIP:` to compare against pre-stored numbers.